# Negating the Legendre's conjecture

Tags: logic

The Legendre's conjecture states that the inteval $(m^2,(m+1)^2)$ contains a
prime $p_n$ for each $m$. I wante to find a negation of it. I have two versions:

(1) There exists an $m$ such that either $p_n≤m^2$ for all $n$, or $p_n≥(m+1)^2$ for all $n$.

or

(2) There is an $m$ such that for all $n$, either $p_n≤m^2$ or $p_n≥(m+1)^2$.

I am not able to choose the right one.

Comment: The negation of $\forall m \exists p_n \ldots$ must be $\exists n \forall p_n \lnot \ldots$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second one should be correct. The conjecture says that for any $m$, there exists a prime in $(m^2, (m+1)^2)$. Its negation should be there exists $m$ such that there is no prime in $(m^2, (m+1)^2)$ or equivalently, any prime is either $\leq m^2$ or $\geq (m+1)^2$ as in (2).

Answer (score 2):

Apart from purely syntactic rules of logic which say that (2) is the correct form (regardless of meaning), note that if we take the semantic (i.e. meaning) into account, then we could see that the statement, for any given $m$, that $p_n\le m^2$ for all $n$, is incorrect (i.e. false) as there are infinitely many primes. Therefore (1) reduces to (and is equivalent to) saying that there is an $m$ such that $p_n\ge(m+1)^2$ for all $n$. This is true only if $m=0$ but I believe you assume $m\ge1$ (for the Legendre's conjecture to make sense), the results being that (1) is simply a false statement (as $p_1=2<4$, and $p_2=3<4\le(m+1)^2$ whenever $m\ge1$).