# I want to see the exact difference between cases (1) and (2)

Tags: logic

This question is related to: [Negating the Legendre's conjecture](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1535430/negating-the-legendres-conjecture/1535490#1535490)

I want to see the exact difference between cases (1) and (2). It seems they are the same. But they are not!. I want to see where I missed some thing in the analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are very different. Version (1) said that all primes $p_n$ satisfy the same one of the two inequalities $p_n\leq m^2$ or $p_n\geq(m+1)^2$. That is, either they all satisfy the first inequality or they all satisfy the second.  Version (2) allowed for the possibility that some primes satisfy the first inequality and others satisfy the second.